# "There's no central alias file bibalias.cfg?"

Tags: bibliographies, warnings, alias

I'm using the  [`bibalias.sty`](http://absatzen.de/#YmliYWxpYXM=) package (enabling easy definition of bibliography key aliases in `.bib` files rather than in your document.)

When I compile my document, I get the following warning:

> Package bibalias Warning: There's no central alias file bibalias.cfg?.

but `bibalias` does work. What's the problem, exactly? Should I just suppress this message?

Comment: Well, the file indicates, that it is maintained. Can you give us a pointer where to find it? A link, a smoke signal?

Comment: @Johannes_B: Yes, edited again...

Comment: `bibalias` looks for a config file, that you can use to define aliases globally and share them between projects. You can set the aliases in your document as well, not defining a global file. The package gives you a warning, that you can savely ignore.

Comment: You might be better off using package `biblatex`, which is a very featurerich replacement of all the packages that deal with the old BibTeX subsystem.

Comment: As Johannes says (and he should make that an answer), the idea is to have a central-ish database, i.e. `bibalias.cfg`, because if you're only worried about one document ever, you might just as well do a search-and-replace once.

Comment: @UlrichSchwarz Why isn't the package on CTAN?

Comment: @egreg: it should make a reasonable attempt to work with `\cite` variants and overloads, and I never had the inclination or the time to gain a comprehensive overview of all the things bibliography that I'd need. It worked well enough for my thesis, everything else is a bonus. (I had to double-check I hadn't uploaded it, though.)

Comment: @UlrichSchwarz: But maybe I have a bunch of papers with some people sharing certain aliases, and with other co-authors, perhaps in a different field, sharing other aliases? Or maybe somebody just sent me some source files using bibalias, with a .bib file s/he wrote with aliases? I think those are perfectly valid use cases which do not merit warnings.

Comment: @UlrichSchwarz Since you are the package maintainer, you should write up the answer. I just cited. ;-)

Comment: @UlrichSchwarz Another ping, maybe you have time to write an answer in 2017 :-)

Answer (score 2):

`bibalias` looks for a config file, that you can use to define aliases globally and share them between projects. You can set the aliases in your document as well, not defining a global file. The package gives you a warning, that you can savely ignore.